# Is there a way to increase the max limit(lines) of the console in Flash Builder?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, console, flash-builder

I need to be able to output some large xml strings, and they are getting cutoff.

Comment: if you are asking about the trace() function, I recommend using the ExternalInterface to call a javascript function that can use console.log() in javascript instead.  It is more reliable than fdb + trace().

Comment: The console in Flash Builder scrolls; doesn't it?  I was unaware of a may line limit.   @Teddy What makies you say that Flash Builder Debug + Trace is unreliable?

Comment: I am a linux user and the fdb command line tool crashes all the time, usually before SWF ever calls the trace() function. Also, it is simpler to not need debug version of Flash player. Keeping Flash debug player up-to-date is a chore.  I struggled with fdb for years and felt like I missed an obvious solution when I finally realized I could use ExternalInterface and console.log().

Comment: @www.Flextras.com It definitely has a limit. Scroll can't help in this case :(

Comment: @Teddy Linux is a special case. Flash Builder isn't supported on Linux officially. And debug version of Flash Player breaks connection to debugger constantly. I think we shouldn't consider Linux here. On Mac and Windows Flash Player is absolutely reliable when using `trace()`. And developing Flex or Flash applications without debug version of Flash Player is rather impossible for me. I'm using debugger very often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Flash Builder is based on Eclipse, you can change that setting by going to Prefrences (Flash Builder -> Preferences or Window -> Preferences depending on your platform).

Next, go to Run/Debug -> Console. Turn off limiting of console output.

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder console scrolls, but was Teddy is referring to is that FB's console has a limit. It doesn't display the entire log. You can just view the flashlog.txt file to see everything. If ur on OSX u can open terminal and type "tail -f /path/to/flashlight.txt" and you can browse the trace output in Terminal. You can also see trace output from SWFs online with tail command.